# Difference between int and int received by ParseInt in java

Tags: java, parseint

```
int i = 0;
int k = Integer.parseInt("12");
int j = k;
System.out.println(i+1 + " " + j+1);
```

Strangely the output received is

```
1 121
```

I can not figure out this basic difference. Please help me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use brackets as follows

```
System.out.println((i+1) + " " + (j+1));
```

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#39990)

> The + operator is syntactically left-associative, no matter whether it
>   is later determined by type analysis to represent string concatenation
>   or addition. In some cases care is required to get the desired result.
>   For example, the expression:
>
> a + b + c is always regarded as meaning: (a + b) + c

Extending this to your scenario

```
i+1 + " " + j+1
```

it becomes

```
(((i + 1) + " ") + j)+1
```

Since `i` is an int so `(i + 1) = 1` , simple *addition*

`" "` is a `String` hence `((i + 1) + " ")` = `1` **WITH SPACE** (String *concatenation*)

Similarly when `j` and last `1` is added, its being added to a `String` hence `String` *concatenation* takes place, which justifies the output that you are getting.

**See**

- [JLS 15.18.1 String Concatenation Operator +](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)

Answer (score 6):

that is beacuse of `" "`.

whenever a String comes, java doesnt do any calculations after that and just append it as string.

So in your case, `i+1` is computed to `1`, but `" " + j+1` has string in it. So, it just appended together to form  `121`

Comment: But why it is not appending on the first case ? If it is true it should be like 01 121

Comment: any primitives/wrappers before the appearance of first String are computed, Anything after that, is just appended together.

Comment: @AurA: because it basically translates to something equivalent to: `" ".concat(j).concat(1)` (or a similar version using StringBuilders, depending on your code and JVM version). It can't guess what you want, so it's pretty natural left to right interpretation.

Comment: @Kshitij thanks for editing the answer not it is quite clear.
haylem thanks for explaination

Comment: No.. it is not like `01 121`... it is conceptually like `(0+1) + " ".append(j).append(1)`

Comment: Yes, I got it he meant that only.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you see this behavior is that the sequence of `+` operators is evaluated left-to-right. So it is evaluated as if parenthesized:

```
System.out.println((((i + 1) + " ") + j) + 1);
```

The first operator adds two `int` values and produces an `int` value. The next `+` adds an `int` to a `String` and produces a `String`. After that, everything is string concatenation. You can introduce your own parentheses to get the result you want.

Comment: Yeah +1, this indeed is the best answer

Answer (score 2):

```
    int i = 0;
    int k = Integer.parseInt("12");
    int j = k;
    System.out.println(i+1 + " " + (j+1));
```

basically when you put + " " + after  this java just appends values as string.

and when you put (j+1) in brackets then its precedence gets higher and it is executes it first and perform sum operation.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `" "` The expression after that gets evaluated as string.

Using brackets `(` and `)` around an expression can solve the problem in hand.

```
System.out.println(i+1 + " " + (j+1));
```

Answer (score 1):

`+` operator is overloaded for addition and String concatenation what you're doing is String concatenation and not addition.. Use brackets for performing addition.

Answer (score 1):

parseint will basically return int (Look at Java API), and there is only one int type in Java. in this example you used " ", where java will treat it as string. in any operation make sure you dont mix up strings with calculations. Always use parenthesis to separate String from calculations.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the + operator has left associativity and has an overloaded function with strings, so when you have this

`int i = 0;
int k = Integer.parseInt("12");
int j = k;
i+1 + " " + j+1`

it first sums 
`i + 1` which gives 1 then it sums `1 + " "`, which uses the overloading function of it to concatenate 1 and " " so it gives a string with the value of "1 ". After that it sums `"1 " + j` and since one of the operands is a string, it does the same behavior and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Interger.parseInt (String str) is a wrapper class method which is used to convert String obj type to primitive data type (int). this are generally  used in collection frame work for converting primitive data type to object and vice versa