# System.out.println("abc"+3+2); why output is abc32 and not abc5?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Difference between int and int received by ParseInt in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008538/difference-between-int-and-int-received-by-parseint-in-java)

> System.out.println("abc"+3+2);  // Output: **abc32**
>
> System.out.println(3+2+"abc");  //Output: **5abc**

What is the reason ?

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008538/difference-between-int-and-int-received-by-parseint-in-java/11008551#11008551

Comment: This question is unprecedented!  <rimshot>

Comment: It adds from left to right. The first case is ("abc"+3)+2, the second is (3+2)+"abc"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
"abc"+3
```

converts 3 to a String

```
"abc3"
```

Then

```
"abc3" + 2
```

Converts 2 to a String as well

```
"abc32"
```

To get a numeric result do

```
"abc" + (3 + 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Because the "+" operator you wrote means "string concatenate", not "add", because it is found with left context being a string value.  In this case, you get a free coercion of the right value via an implicit ToString.

You'd probably get what you wanted by writing

```
System.out.println("abc"+(3+2))
```

The "3" is found with no left context, so it is just an integer; the following "+" is found with left context integer, so it is interpreted as a real add operator, thus (3+2) gives 5.  That result is found with left context of "+", so it is coerced to a string and concatenated to produce "abc5".

Answer (score 1):

Expressions are evaluated from left to right (after apply operator precedence order). If one of the arguments for operator + is a string, the result is a concatenated string parsing the int to String

In the first case:

```
"abc" + 3 -> "abc3" // String + int -> concatenate
"abc3" + 2 -> "abc32" // String + int -> concatenate
```

In the second case:

```
3 + 2 -> 5 // int + int -> add
5 + "abc" -> "5abc" // int + String -> concatenate
```

Comment: *Operands* are evaluated from left to right. Expressions are evaluated according to operator precedence. In this case it's the same thing, but it isn't always.

Comment: @EJP Right. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The evaluation of an expression where operators have the same precedence is from left to right. In this case, the different order in the expressions causes the operator + to mean:

1. a concatenation of Strings (an Integer is implicitly converted `toString()`)
2. a sum between 2 Integers

   "abc"+3+2 = (("abc" + 3) + 2) = ("abc3" + 2) = "abc32"

   3+2+"abc" = ((3 + 2) + "abc") = (5 + "abc") = "5abc"

Answer (score 0):

In the first case 3 and 2 are treated as Strings and then concatenated separately to `abc`.

In the second case the sum `3+2` is calculated and then it is concatenated to `abc`.